# Which is the best way to use SQLite DB?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, windows-store-apps

am developing a Windows Store 8.1 app.

I want to save some data locally in my app, so am using SQLite i created a DB and added few tables in that and i have added some data to that from Code.

Which one is the best option from the following?

1) Creating the DB from the code for the first time opening the app

2) Attaching  the DB file with predefined structure in the app with in the solution folder.

Please suggest me the best solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

For my own apps I use the first option: creating the database when the app's been opened for the first time.

```
    public MyAppDataContext()
    {
        connection = new SQLiteConnection(new SQLitePlatformWinRT(), Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, DATABASE_NAME));

        Initialize();
    }

    private void Initialize()
    {
        connection.CreateTable<Foo>();
        connection.CreateTable<Bar>();
        connection.CreateTable<Bas>();
    }
```

There's no need to worry that you'll needlessly create tables everytime the app starts, because `SQLiteConnection.CreateTable` uses a `create if not exists` [behind the scenes](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/blob/master/src/SQLite.cs#L383).